# Is there a way to set url namespace for two or more apps in django?

Tags: python, django, namespaces, django-urls

What I am trying to do is to have common namespace for two or more apps.

Lets say I have two apps in my project. Each of them has a url module for public and for administration. The structure looks like this:

```
|-- app1
|   |-- views
|   |-- models
|   |-- urls
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- public.py
|   |   |-- administration.py
|-- app2
|   |-- views
|   |-- models
|   |-- urls
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- public.py
|   |   |-- administration.py
```

Then I want those urls modules include and set the common namespace for public urls and administration urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^administration/', include('app1.urls.administration', namespace="administration")),
    url(r'^administration/', include('app2.urls.administration', namespace="administration")),

    url(r'^', include('app1.urls.public', namespace="public")),
    url(r'^', include('app2.urls.public', namespace="public")),

)
```

This is all nice and dandy, but the `reverse` method doesn't work quite rigth. It seems like, once I declare some namespace for an app, I cannot add any more patterns to the namespace. So the reverse returns match for the urls from the `app1`, but doesn't seem to find urls from `app2`.

```
> reverse("administration:app1_url") 
/administration/app1/url/
> reverse("administration:app2_url")
*** NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'app2_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Is there any way to do it?

I need this because I have same names for the urls in public and in administration and I don't want to prefix them, when there is a way to namespace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
admin_patterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^', include('app1.urls.administration'),
   url(r'^', include('app2.urls.administration'),
)   
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^administration/', include(admin_patterns, namespace="administration")),
)
```

Is this what you are trying to do? Of course the problem here is that any urls from `app1` will be resolved before `app2` so if you have the same urls in the administration section of both apps then only `app1` will ever resolve.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I tried the same, but forgot to call the `patterns()`. Thanks!